# How to return a multiple Column by passing two values in a function/procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I didn't find information on getting multiple rows/columns from an oracle functions/procedure.

Is this possible? If so, any syntax or examples would be much useful.

Answer (score 2):

You have [COLLECT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions024.htm#i1271564) function:

> COLLECT takes as its argument a column of any type and creates a nested table of the input type out of the rows selected.
>
> ```
> SELECT CAST(COLLECT(phone_numbers) AS phone_book_t) 
> FROM customers;
> ```

For procedure see answers with [multiple out parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37888223/oracle-run-procedure-with-one-in-parameter-and-multiple-out-parameter)